# Use editors as fallback if no authors are given

Tags: biblatex

My university requires me to use the editors field where the authors should be if no authors are given.

I use biblatex.

```
@book{mustermann2010,
    author={Mustermann, Max},
    title={TeX},
    year={2010}
}
```

Should be the same as:

```
@book{mustermann2010,
    editor={Mustermann, Max},
    title={TeX},
    year={2010}
}
```

Both should yield:

> Mustermann, M. (2010): TeX.

At the moment, I get the above for the first one and an empty authors field for the second one.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I get "Mustermann, M., ed. (2010). TeX." as I would expect. What style do you use? It would be best if you could provide an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)?

Comment: Is there any update here? Can you give some additional detail?

Comment: Sorry, @Moewe! I was sick for a few days and didn't check SE. Thank you for your input. When trying to create an MWE, I found that I had erroneously called the field `editors` instead of `editor`. Now it works. Simple mistake!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP had erroneously called the `editor` field `editors`, a problem that could not be seen from the question and has since been resolved.